# How can I change the output display of my pagination?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, pagination, terms

How can I change the output display of my pagination? I have been trying for the past few hours to format the output of my pagination links (1,2,3, etc.) to resemble the below:

[image: Pagination Screenshot - GOAL]

I have been unable to modify the code to get it even close to this. Could someone please point me in the right direction of what I need to be doing?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
        $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    }elseif( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
        $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
    }else{
        $paged = 1;
    }

    $per_page = 3;
    $number_of_terms = wp_count_terms( 'series' ); // This counts the total number terms in the taxonomy with a function)
    $paged_offset = ($paged - 1) * $per_page;

    $args = array(
        'orderby'           => 'ID',
        'order'             => 'DESC',
        'hide_empty'        => 0,
        'number'            => $per_page,
        'offset'            => $paged_offset
    );  

    $terms = get_terms('series', $args);  

    foreach($terms as $term){ ?>

        <div class="block_item article">
            <div  class="article_image" style="background: url('<?php the_field('series_artwork', $term); ?>'); background-size: cover; background-position: 50%;"></div>
            <h4 class="section_label"><?php the_field('date', $term); ?></h4>
            <div class="block_item_content">
                <h3><?php echo $term->name; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $term->description; ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'series'); ?>" class="button_styling">
                    Read More
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php } 

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    echo paginate_links( 
        array(
            'before_page_number' => '<div class="pagination"><span>Page '. $paged .' of ' . $term->max_num_pages . '</span></div>',
            'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'  => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total'   => ceil( $number_of_terms / $per_page ),
            'prev_text' => __(''),
            'next_text' => __('')
        ) 
    );
?>
```

If you can get it to work with my existing function (something I have been trying to do) then bonus points to you!

**functions.php**

```
// numbered pagination
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{  
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }   

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";  
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
 }
}
```

**Function Call**

```
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
     pagination($terms->max_num_pages);
} ?>
```

Thank you for any help that can be provided!

Comment: Why don't you just use `paginate_links()`? You can add the "Page {x} of {y}" via custom code, and you can use `mid_size` and `end_size` to change/adjust the number of links displayed.

Comment: @SallyCJ, hello and thank you for your response. I was not aware I could do that with the `paginate_links()` function. I'm still learning PHP and WordPress development. How would I go about adding the "Page {x} of {y}?

Comment: Hi Peter. I posted an answer. Check it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will loop through a custom taxonomy and pull all the associated terms.

```
<?php if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
        $page = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    }

    $per_page = 9;
    $totalterms   = wp_count_terms( 'series' ); 
    $totalpages   = ceil( $totalterms / $per_page );
    $paged_offset = ( $page > 0 ) ?  $per_page * ( $page - 1 ) : 1;

    $args = array(
        'orderby'       => 'ID', 
        'order'         => 'DSC',
        'hide_empty'    => true, 
        'exclude'       => array(), 
        'exclude_tree'  => array(), 
        'include'       => array(),
        'number'        => $per_page, 
        'fields'        => 'all', 
        'slug'          => '', 
        'parent'         => '',
        'hierarchical'  => true, 
        'child_of'      => 0, 
        'get'           => '', 
        'name__like'    => '',
        'pad_counts'    => false, 
        'offset'        => $paged_offset, 
        'search'        => '', 
        'cache_domain'  => 'core'
    );

    $terms = get_terms('series', $args);  

    foreach($terms as $term){ ?>

        <div class="block_item article">
            <div class="block_item_overlay"></div>
            <div  class="article_image" style="background: url('<?php the_field('series_artwork', $term); ?>'); background-size: cover; background-position: 50%;"></div>
            <h4 class="section_label"><?php the_field('date', $term); ?></h4>
            <div class="block_item_content">
                <h3><?php echo $term->name; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $term->description; ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, 'series'); ?>" class="button_styling">
                    Read More
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php } 

    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
    printf( '<div class="pagination"><span>Page '.$page.' of '.$totalpages.'</span>', 
        custom_page_navi( $totalpages, $page, 3, 0 ) 
    );

    echo paginate_links( 
        array(
            'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'format'  => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'total'   => ceil( $totalterms / $per_page ),
            'prev_next' => false
        ) 
    ); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could see that you are trying to achieve the following output:

```
<div class="pagination">
  <span>Page {current} of {total pages}</span>
  {links here}
</div>
```

And you attempted it like so:

```
'before_page_number' => '<div class="pagination"><span>Page '. // wrapped for clarity
  $paged .' of ' . $term->max_num_pages . '</span></div>'
```

But that will actually add the markup before *each and every* page number in the generated links. (And the `$term->max_num_pages` is also a `null` because in that context, `$term` doesn't have a `max_num_pages` property.)

So here's how you could achieve the expected output:

```
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$cur_page = max( 1, $paged );
$num_pages = ceil( $number_of_terms / $per_page );
$links = paginate_links(
    array(
        'base'    => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format'  => '/page/%#%',
        'current' => $cur_page,
        'total'   => $num_pages,
        'prev_text' => __(''),
        'next_text' => __('')
    )
);

// If there are links to paginate, display the pagination.
if ( $links ) {
    $before = '<span>Page '. $cur_page .' of ' . $num_pages . '</span>';
    echo '<div class="pagination">' . $before . ' ' . $links . '</div>';
}
```

See the `paginate_links()` [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/) for more details on that function, such as the `mid_size` and `end_size` parameters that control the number of pages/links to be displayed.

Comment: Thank you Sally. I will check this out tomorrow morning and get back to you. I appreciate the response!

Comment: This solution didn't end up working for me. I ended up solving for the pagination by  declaring `$totalterms` and `$totalpages` variables and printf'ing them. I'll post the solution that worked for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi Peter. I'm not sure why the code doesn't work for you, but [here](https://pastebin.com/R7BZTbJV)'s the full code I used (for testing). I did have the `$cur_page` and `$max_num_pages` which hold the current page and total number of pages respectively, and the `$paged`, `$number_of_terms`, and `$per_page` are defined earlier in your code. (I forgot to change the `prev_text` and `next_text` to `''` in the answer, though that shouldn't cause the code to not working.)